# Running older version JointsWP

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, gulp

I have an older project running JointsWP 4. Somehow I can't run and compile anymore. Unfortunately this goes beyond my knowledge.

I've tried to run npm install again but it just trows up errors.
How do I get this project back up running?

Many thanks

```
...

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/bramroos/Sites/alert/wp-content/themes/alert/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.1.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/bramroos/Sites/alert/wp-content/themes/alert/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/bramroos/Sites/alert/wp-content/themes/alert/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/bramroos/.npm/_logs/2020-11-25T13_15_12_661Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages indicate you are trying to use `node-sass@3.13.1` with Node.js 12.18.0. The [support table for `node-sass`](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/tree/7105b0abd35377a52a7df8994aa45aa8395a18e4#node-version-support-policy) says that Node.js 12.18.0 requires `node-sass` 4.12 or newer.

Judging from the support table, `node-sass` 3.x is entirely unsupported at this time. You can try to update `node-sass` to 4.x or you can use a Node.js version manager like `nvm` to try to build it with an older version of `node`.

Comment: Thanks Trott. I've decided to update the theme to the latest JointsWP. Problem solved.